# jQuery Removing list item with jQuery, Fade out - Delete from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, fade

Right now I am using a jQuery inline script and what I want to do is add a delete option where if deleted, it will fade out and remove from the DOM.  Right now, this is not hooked up to a database at all, I am using a VIN decoder so these are the default features it pulls.

The code I provided below, of course, deletes every single list item.  I want to only delete the list item that I clicked "Delete" for.  I'm not sure how to accomplish this because there is no unique class or anything.

[image]

**jQuery Code:**

```
// plugin defaults
$.inlineEdit.defaults = {
   hover: 'ui-state-hover',
   value: '',
   save: '',
   buttons: '<button class="save">save</button> <button class="cancel">cancel</button> <a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>',
   placeholder: 'Click to edit',
   control: 'input',
   cancelOnBlur: false,
   saveOnBlur: false
};

.find( 'a.delete' )
            .bind( 'click', function( event ) {

                $("li.editable").fadeOut(300, function() { 
                    $(this).remove(); 
                });

                return false;
            })
        .end()
```

Comment: Can you post the generated `html` so we can get a better idea of its structure?

Comment: Though the answer below is right, I'm guessing you didn't provide the complete code `.find( 'a.delete' )` will probably generate an object not found error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace `$("li.editable")` with `$(this).closest("li.editable")` and you should be fine.

Comment: yep. don't even need the `.editable`, a simple `$(this).closest('li')` will work

Comment: quick question.  the generated list has an even and odd row class, of course with the different colors.  when I delete one in the middle, I will have two of the same color now.  is there any way around that? I  can post more code if needed.

Comment: @vol7ron: True, but it's always possible that the link will be buried in a sublist (although that doesn't appear to be the case from the image OP provided).

Comment: @Drew: You will need to add code inside your `.bind("click")` function to re-color the rows. Something like `$("li.editable:even")` (or `:odd`) will make it easier  -- http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/

Comment: @mblase75: I considered that, but the context of how the link is used doesn't make me think that will ever happen.

Comment: @Drew: like what mblase said, `$('li.editable:even').css('background','#ee9');` or something like that